# MySQL/MariaDB Drop Table if Created

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

So I want to create a trigger or some other kind of method for dropping an entire table if it is created. I have the following SQL query but as of this moment I'm stuck.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
    TRIGGER `kill_migrations` AFTER CREATE ON SCHEMA
BEGIN
    IF SYS.DICTIONARY_OBJ_TYPE = 'TABLE' THEN
        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS django_migrations
END;
```

How do I drop a table if it is created? The current SQL query provided has a syntax error around "Drop Table".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) and [the MariaDB manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/create-trigger/#trigger_event) clearly limit `trigger_event_` to `INSERT | UPDATE | DELETE`.  That is, `CREATE` is not an option.  Note how the error `1064 ... syntax to use near 'CREATE ON ...` points exactly there.